# ¿Cuál es la lógica detrás de las declaraciones if/else en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

En mis lecciones de Javascript, se presenta un caso en el cual cambio el orden de lógica de las declaraciones. Paso de

```
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 10) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}

orderMyLogic(7);
>>> "Less than 5"
```

a cambiar el orden de los números.

```
function orderMyLogic(val) {
  if (val < 5) {
    return "Less than 5";
  } else if (val < 10) {
    return "Less than 10";
  } else {
    return "Greater than or equal to 10";
  }
}

orderMyLogic(7);
>>> "Less than 10"
```

Como te fijarás, cambié el orden de los números. En el primero estaba de mayor a menor, en el segundo cuadro de menor a mayor. El resultado es diferente cuando los cambias.

¿Cuál es la lógica detrás de esto? ¿Por qué hay resultados distintos cuando los números son los mismos y así la lógica?

Comment: El primer código devuelve "Less than 10" no "Less than 5" con lo cual no tiene sentido la pregunta. ¿Hay un error? ¿Qué usaste para probar el código? Si decides corregir la pregunta considera usar [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El codigo de evaluacion correcto para el numero es el segundo** y explico la razon:

**En el primer codigo;**

Si evaluas un numero 4 en esta condicion `if (val < 10)` que diria si 4 es menor a 10 entonces ejecutara el contenido del primer if que seria  `return "Less than 5";` dejando de una lado la evaluacion del segundo else `if (val < 5)` ya que esta condicion solamente se evaluaria cuando **val** sea mayor a **10**. entonces el primer `if (val < 10)` no lo seria verdad pasando por el segundo `if (val < 5)` que tampoco seria verdad y quedando solamente el else evaluando `return "Greater than or equal to 10";` pero nunca se sabria si el numero era menor a 5.

**Para el segundo codigo:**

si `val = 3` entonces el primer if evaluara `if (3 < 5)` lo cual significa que 3 es menor a 5 y se puede ejecutar el contenido del codigo  `return "Less than 5";`

si val = 6 entonces el primer if evalua  `if (6 < 5)` que es falso porque 6 no es menor a 5, pasando al segundo `if (6 < 10)` lo cual es verdad porque 6 es menor a 10 y muestra: `return "Less than 10";`

Si `val = 11` entonces el primer `if (11 < 5)` falso, pasa al segundo `if (11 < 10)` es tambien falso con lo que ejecutara el else `return "Greater than or equal to 10";`

**Aqui te adjunto el codigo para ejecutando**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="number" id="numero">
        <input type="button" id="boton" value="evaluar">
        <p id="resultado"></p>

    <script>
       function orderMyLogic(val) {
        if (val < 5) {
            return "Less than 5";
            } else if (val < 10) {
                return "Less than 10";
            } else {
                return "Greater than or equal to 10";
            }
        }
        
        document.getElementById('boton').onclick = function() {
           //  tomar valor de campo number
           var valor = document.getElementById('numero').value;
           var  resultado = orderMyLogic(valor);
           document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML= resultado;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

El resultado en ambos ejemplos es "Less than 10". Puede que tengas un error en la pregunta.

De todas formas el orden de operaciones condicionales **importa y mucho**.

Si en tu ejemplos hubieras invocado `orderMyLogic` usando 3 en lugar de 10 como argumento, el resultado hubiera sido distinto.

La razón es que este código se evalúa de forma secuencial, por lo tanto cuando una condición es verdadera el bloque de código asociado a ella se ejecutará y retornará.

Probemos usando 3 como argumento. En los dos ejemplos la condición del primer `if` es válida, por lo tanto se ejecutará el código dentro de él, retornando "Less than 10" en el primer ejemplo y "Less than 5" en el segundo.

En este caso debes ordenar tu lógica de condiciones más restrictivas a menos restrictivas. Es por ello que el segundo ejemplo es el correcto. Este es un problema común, y lo es tanto que se pregunta en muchas entrevistas laborales, puedes googlear el problema "FizzBuzz" (es muy similar).